# Side navbar responsive collapse Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make a sidebar menu responsive in mobile devices, but I can't figure how, I'm new on Boostrap, and I follow the documentation on boostrap official page, but I can't find a example a sidebar menu collapse.
I want something like this:

On large devices: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvGcA.png]

On mobile devices:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWSaT.png]

I'd appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Look into css media queries: A couple of resources that may help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries & https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp